# JS how to call this function?

Tags: javascript

how can I call 'del' function? because name.del() and this.name no work :(

```
 var name = function(){
     this.del = function(){
     }
    name.del(); // no work 
    this.del(); // no work
}
```

Comment: This depends how `name` is called. `this` does not always have the same reference, but if you do `this.del()` inside `name`, it will always work.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

In order to help you, we must understand what you are trying to do. If you solely want to call a function in your anonymous one, you could do this:

```
 var name = function(){

    function del(){

    }

    del();
}
```

However, if you would like to use `name` in a class-instance way, you were on the right track.

```
function MyClass(){

  this.del = function(){

  }

}

// Instantiate

var name = new MyCLass();

name.del();
```

There are numerous additional ways to to do things.
What you shoud go for heavily depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You have declare `name` as a function, but you also declare `del` as another function, `member of the first`. This syntax allow you to use `name` as an `Object` (reffer to POO) or as a function.

```
            var name = function () {
                this.del = function () {
                    console.log("Hello");
                };
                this.del();
            };
            name();
```

This will cause `name()` to be executed & `name.del` too.
You can also auto run it by this way.

```
            (function () {
                this.del = function () {
                    console.log("Hello");
                };
            )(); // autoExecute
```

If you want to keep a result of your function for futher use...

```
            var name = (function () {
                this.del = function () {
                    return "StackOverflow";
                };
            )();
            alert(name);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var name={

    add:function(){
        alert('add');
    },
    del:function(){
        alert('del');
    },

}
    name.del();
```

here name is an object which inside it can have some functions and vars 
i think this can help you

Comment: This is neither what the OP is trying to do in his example

Comment: This is not wrong per se. However, the OP is trying to call a function inside another, anonymous one. He does'nt make clear what he is trying to do, so throwing some solution at him without losing at least a few words on what that actually does, isn't very helpful IMO

Comment: @Sprottenwels you mean that my answer dose not have explanation ?

Comment: exactly. Please consider adding some words, so that the OP is able to understand what your code does and when it is reasonable to use it

Comment: @Sprottenwels I added some explanation : )